# Angular - need help on architectural principals for larger applications

Tags: angular, architecture

We have been building some SPA applications using AngularJS - relative small to medium applications. I've been trying to get deeper on the structural / architectural side. Reading alot of posts, having a look at alot of youtube videos ... just trying to get good and complete ideas or tools on how the best devops approaches...

I have the feeling there are alot of tools available - alot of methods - alot of ideas ... but not really clear which tools are best practices and which set of tools form a good match in providing a professional development environment for upcomming larger Angular applications.

**I'm looking for personal experiences, ideas, links or YouTube links that can give us far better insights on have we can setup a AngularJS development - production environment for a multi-person development team.**

It's maybe a really general question - yes that's true - but because we don't really know or have experience with all the different tools, it's hard to determine which ones we should use... Maybe we are looking for some experiences of other developers ... Pointing out the tools or processes they use inside their development - producten cycle and how the architecture of their large AngularJS webapps look like.

Anything is welcome... Thanks!

Comment: you are being super general and want specific answers. There are tons of tools available, to choose which one really depends on specific things about your team

Comment: It's general, yes true - but because we don't know really what to pick and what not to ... Maybe we are looking for some experiences of other developers ... Pointing out the tools or processes they use...

Comment: I see both tags on your message, so I'm unclear. Are you looking for AngularJS (v1) advice or Angular (v2+) advice?

Comment: Thanks for poiting out - i've updated the tag. We are looking for Angular 2+ advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

John Papa's [Angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) is widely considered the best starting point for how to structure an Angular application. He has pointers for both v1 and v2.